# Rails: How to debug in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I've deployed to a VPS, but when visiting to my site, message shows:

> We're sorry but something went wrong.

How could I start to debug?

I've deployed this commit successfully to heroku before. And before pushing to VPS, the site was running well. 
I tried to see the `log/production.log`, but it only says `Connecting to database specified by database.yml`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with logs. Set more verbose log level to see what happens: set `config.log_level = :debug` in your `config/environments/production.rb`

More general, try something like [errbit](https://github.com/errbit/errbit) to see details about your production errors.